# SQL query doesn't work. Possible syntax error

Tags: mysql

Seems to be strange but very simple SQL query doesn't work for me.

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET `meta_value` = REPLACE(post_meta, `http://url/`, `http://new_url`)
```

Error message appears 'a new statement was found but no delimiter was found between it and the previous one (REPLACE) and when I'm trying to execute the code -  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1.  Please advise.

Comment: You need straight single quotes around the string values, not backticks.

Comment: Edit your question and show the table(s) that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your specific issue is the use of backticks rather than single quotes.  However, I think a better way to express the logic is:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
    SET meta_value = CONCAT('http://new_url', SUBSTRING(post_meta, 12) )
    WHERE meta_value LIKE 'http://url/%' AND
          meta_key = ??;
```

This uses the `WHERE` clause to filter out rows that should not be updated.  It also ensures that the update is only to the occurrence of `'http://url/'` at the beginning the string -- usually the logic that is intended.

Comment: If I change backtricks to single quotes it is still the same problem...

Comment: Do you really intend `post_meta` for the `replace()` and `meta_value` for the assignment?